# Buying seforim online

Tags: jewish-books, transactions

Is there a problem with buying seforim from a (non-Jewish) online seller, such as Amazon?  eg. do we need to worry about how they have treated the seforim (eg. thrown the packages around)?  If there is a problem with them selling seforim online, should we buy them to get them out of their ownership, or should we avoid buying them so that they aren't encouraged to buy more to sell?  Does that depend on whether they are selling new or 2nd hand - eg. an eBay seller who has 1 sefer amongst many non-Jewish books may be best to buy from as they are unlikely to restock?

Comment: I don't get the question. Many seforim stores ship / deliver seforim through their websites - how is this any different?

Comment: As far as I understand, unused seforim have no kedusha.

Comment: @Dov I assume that if you buy from a Jewish seller then it is their problem to ensure that the seforim are treated respectfully, but a non-Jewish seller won't do that

Comment: @shmosel Is there a source for that?  Would that even apply to a Sefer Torah??

Comment: I assume it applies only to printed seforim. Don't know the source.

Comment: On the other hand: https://www.sefaria.org/Teshuva_MeAhava_Part_I.9.2

Comment: @shmosel Because question is when is printed material Shaimot and there's many opinions, was it used yet, is it koach gabra, etc.

Comment: @moses a sefer Torah is never unused since the sofer reads as he writes. A printed book may have never even been touched by a human

Comment: @shmosel So is it better to buy used seforim (vs new ones) if it looks like the seller is non-Jewish so that we know that they aren't going to be thrown away?

Comment: I would think so. Even if new ones have kedusha, it can't compare to something that was actually used.